# Hide script extension and get value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a php based project. I want to know --

=> how to hide the script extension shown in url? Like stack.php should look as only stack

=> is there any way to hide get values? Or for security reason how to handle get values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to hide the script extension shown in url? Like stack.php should look as only stack

It's possible but makes no sense.

> is there any way to hide get values?

It's impossible and makes no sense

GET values defines an unique page address. Without them your code will be unable to tell which info have to be shown.
To make whatever values secure, you have to filter and sanitize them, not hide. You merely cannot hide anything from user who is actually sending them values from their browser. 
So, concerning hyperlinks, just keep your current setup as is - it's okay.

> Or for security reason how to handle get values?

It depends on the further use of these values. There are plenty of answers on the matter already.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding Script Extension in .htaccess check the accepted answer here....

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess

Hiding GET Values check the answers to  the same question here

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2642522/how-can-i-hide-a-get-variable-to-be-more-secured-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Check you have `mod_rewrite` installed and then put this in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

This is of course assuming that you're using Apache.